# Datejs issue with previous dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datejs

The query `last Sunday - 7days` returns `Wednesday, July 22, 2015 12:00:00 AM` (tested on [datejs.com](http://www.datejs.com)). If the issue is unresolvable, can [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) serve similar queries, especially for dates in the past (the docs do not show equivalents)?

**Update:** [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates) - this great library solved the problem:

```
Date.create('this Sunday') // equivalent to "last Sunday"
Date.create('last Monday') // equivalent to "last Sunday - 7days"
Date.create('six days before Sunday') // equivalent to "last Sunday - 7days"
```

Answer (score 1):

Date.js hasn't been updated in 8 years.  It has lots of bugs.  You can try the [DateJS: Evolved](https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs/) fork, which has resolved many of them.

Moment.js does not currently have the functionality to interpret a string like that.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the new version do not fix the issue.